# ClassNotFoundException: org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, docx4j

So here we go again. My head is banging on my PC about few hours, I can't figured out what to do. On my local PC I run the java code from **Intellij Idea**. It works. Now I have to create `jar` file to make it able to use on some remote server. I added all libraries, jars that my program needs at project settings (Added libraries at Artifacts section). But it doesn't work running at remote server. What imports my program needs:

```
import org.docx4j.dml.CTBlip;
import org.docx4j.jaxb.XPathBinderAssociationIsPartialException;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.PartName;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.relationships.RelationshipsPart;
import org.docx4j.relationships.Relationship;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/docx4j/openpackaging/exceptions/Docx4JException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
Could not find the main class: Main. Program will exit.
```

So is the problem in creating the jar? I missed something?

Comment: Look at the generated jar.  Does it contain any information about where to find org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException class?

Comment: Most likely the problem is with the jar you created. Easiest way to verify is extract your jar and check if the required libraries are present.

Comment: Yes, the jar file is about 40Mb and all libraries are inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException is in the docx4j.jar file, so make sure that (and all docx4j's dependencies) is on your classpath.

Comment: Thank you. My dream to have jar included all external jar in a one file crashed for now. I can't solve it. One way to avoid this error now seems to create jar with manifest described path to external jars.

Comment: So I solved it. I won Intellij Idea) You made me look at right path. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I faced with a similar issue when original docx4j jars were not loaded by a classloader.

I tried these ones:

- docx4j-3.1.0.jar
- docx4j-3.2.1.jar

For some reason, Midnight Commander couldn't open them (by enter pressing) from the first attempt and reported "Inconsistent extfs archive". The problem was solved by the jar recreation

```
# run in a directory containing just single original docx4j jar file
unzip docx4j-3.2.1.jar
rm -r docx4j-3.2.1.jar
jar cf docx4j-3.2.1.jar *
```

Now the new jar is opened in MC without problems (at least in my case) and its classes are loaded and `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` is not thrown anymore.

**UPDATE**

JIC, I just checked which JDK the jar I used belong to.

It is OpenJDK 64-Bit 1.7.0_79, Linux Mint 17.